# How many unique endings does chrono trigger have?

Tags: chrono-trigger

It is well known that Chrono Trigger has multiple endings, and it is even explicitly mentioned in the original manual for the SNES version that depending on where you are when you defeat the final boss, you wil get a different ending.

How many unique endings does Chrono Trigger have, and what are the unlock conditions for each of the endings?

Answer (score 2):

From this [wiki](https://chrono.fandom.com/wiki/List_of_Chrono_Trigger_endings) page, we can see that there are 13 "good" endings, one with 5 "sub endings", depending on what you have done in the storyline, one that is exclusive to DS/Android/iOS and PC, and one "bad" ending:

1. Bad Ending: The Apocalypse
2. Ending 1: Beyond Time

   - Ending 1a: Float    Away
   - Ending 1b: Follow that Cat!!!
   - Ending 1c: Save the Chancellor
   - Ending 1d: On that Day, 10 Years Ago
   - Ending 1e: Revenge for Cyrus
3. Ending 2: Reunion
4. Ending 3: The Dream Project
5. Ending 4: The Successor    of Guardia
6. Ending 5: Good Night
7. Ending 6: The Legendary Hero
8. Ending    7: The Unknown Past
9. Ending 8: People of the Times
10. Ending 9: The Oath
11. Ending 10: Dino Age
12. Ending 11: What the Prophet Seeks
13. Ending 12:    Memory Lane
14. Ending 13: Dream's Epilogue (DS, iOS/Android, and Windows    exclusive)

Comment: Do you mind adding the unlock conditions for each of the endings to your answer, since the wiki page completely spoils what happens in the endings.

Comment: You can find that all on the wiki page, which I have provided the link for